# Joomla 3.x component: How to set dynamically the directory for media field in admin form?

Tags: joomla, field, components

i've a question :
is it possible to set the directory parameter of a media field joomla dependng on the content of another field ?

ex.

```
        <field
            id="dir"
            name="dir"
            type="text"
            required="true"
            label="Dir"
            description="dir_Desc"
            class="inputbox"
            size="40"/>     

<field name="photo" type="media"
    label="PHOTO"
    description="PHOTO" 
    **directory= ??dir??** 
/>
```

Comment: You will have to override the media form field file to do this

Comment: Thanks for your prompt replay. Can you suggest me a way to do that or a link to an article that explay how to do ? :-) Paolo

Comment: This will show you how to [Create a Custom Form Field](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type). The code that will go into your PHP file will need to be copied from `libraries\cms\form\field\media.php`

Comment: again thanks for your suggestions. :-) Paolo

Comment: Dear Lodder, many thanks. i've modified the field "media" and now all works as expected. :-):-):-):-):-)